# Unable to return correct url path on redirecting an unauthenticated user to login page in a spring security extended multi tenant application

Tags: spring, spring-security, multi-tenant

First, my apologies if the question as constructed does not seem right for the problem i am about to explain.

I am working on spring based multi tenant application that extends spring security.
The application is such that tenants are identified via URL path.
For instance, 3 different tenants' products URL will look like below

```
http://localhost:8084/webapp/companyA/products
http://localhost:8084/webapp/companyB/products
http://localhost:8084/webapp/companyB/products
```

I am trying to redirect an unauthenticated user who tries to access restricted page of any the companies to login page.
For instance an unauthenticated user tries to access

```
http://localhost:8084/webapp/companyA/admin
```

the user should be redirected to

```
http://localhost:8084/webapp/companyA/login
```

The problem i am facing is that i am not able to return the right URL to the user even though the user gets redirected to login page.
For example, if tested using companyA, the URL returned as displayed on the browser's address bar is

```
http://localhost:8084/webapp/{tenant}/login
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8084/webapp/companyA/login
```

My code

Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/{tenant}")
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String getLoginPage() {  

        return "login";  

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String getAdminPage() {  

        return "admin";  

    }

}
```

Spring security class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/{tenant}/admin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/{tenant}/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/{tenant}/secured-login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password");

    // rest of the code

}
```

Please if this approach is not right, a better approach will be so much welcomed and appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think, that *`.loginPage("/{tenant}/login")`* and *`.loginProcessingUrl("/{tenant}/secured-login")`* should work? Is it documented in Spring Security Reference?

Comment: @dur It is not documented. I have googled all I can for documentation/tutorial/articles on securing a multi tenant application using spring security but couldn't find any. I only have to put up that code for other developers to have a clue of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: As I wrote *one login page*, I meant one URL for the login page. The `{tenant}` is not neccessary in the URL.

Comment: So how will you then be able to identify the right tenant at login time for a user who requested the login page directly?

Comment: Option A: after login choose on homepage is not a good idea. Option B: choose on login page was my initial plan. Option C: choose on homepage then proceed to login page is currently my option of choice. Reason being that knowing the tenant before login will help me customise the login page to give the client sense of ownership.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150330/discussion-between-perry-and-dur).